# How to isolate regions of a 3d surface with a constrained height?

Tags: numpy, where-clause, histogram2d

I have a 2-variable discrete function represented in the form of a tuple through the following line of code:

```
hist_values, hist_x, hist_y = np.histogram2d()
```

Where you can think of a *non-smooth 3d surface* with *hist_values* being the height of the surface at grids with edge coordinates of (*hist_x*, *hist_y*).

Now, I would like to collect those grids for which *hist_values* is above some *threshold* level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply compare the `hist_values` with the `threshold`, this would give you a mask as an array of `bool` which can be used in slicing, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

# prepare random input
arr1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)
arr2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)

# compute 2D histogram
hist_values, hist_x, hist_y = np.histogram2d(arr1, arr2)

mask = hist_values > threshold  # the array of `bool`
hist_values[mask]  # only the values above `threshold`
```

Of course, the values are then collected in a flattened array.
Alternatively, you could also use `mask` to instantiate a masked-array object (using `numpy.ma`, see docs for more info on it).

If you are after the coordinates at which this is happening, you should use `numpy.where()`.

```
# i0 and i1 contain the indices in the 0 and 1 dimensions respectively
i0, i1 = np.where(hist_values > threshold)

# e.g. this will give you the first value satisfying your condition
hist_values[i0[0], i1[0]]
```

For the corresponding values of `hist_x` and `hist_y` you should note that these are the boundaries of the bins, and not, for example, the mid-values, therefore you could resort to the lower or upper bound of it.

```
# lower edges of `hist_x` and `hist_y` respectively...
hist_x[i0]
hist_y[i1]

# ... and upper edges
hist_x[i0 + 1]
hist_y[i1 + 1]
```

Comment: Thanks Norok, This will give me hist_values above the limit. What I want are the *x*, and *y* arrays for which this holds.Could you please let me know how to extract these arrays?

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing. To get mid-values, I just added half-width of the bins in each direction to all elements of the arrays.